# Postfix ignores virtual_transport setting for LMTP

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I was trying to use LMTP instead of the standard LDA via UNIX-pipe for the mail transport from postfix to dovecot.

I configured dovecot and installed dovecot-lmtp, now i have an (non-public) LMTP-service on port 19382 running.

I tested LMTP via telnet and it works perfectly.

In my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` i got `virtual_transport` set to

`virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost:19382`,

but postfix does not connect to the lmtp service (tested it with `tcpflow`). 
There are no error messages in `mail.log`.

Whats wrong with my config? Do you need more info?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got a solution.

I'm now using  `mailbox_transport` instead of `virtual_transport` and it works.

Does anyone now why postfix ignored `virtual_transport`?

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

`mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost:19382`